# Unity - Adding delays to my buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a snake game and I'm running into a problem where if I hit my inputs (up, down, left, right) too fast, my snake runs into itself.  I've tried to create a timer under Update() to regulate my movements but I find my snake to still be running into itself from time to time.

I use InvokeRepeating() to move my snake every 0.05 seconds and I have 2 methods of inputs: 1) Update to listen for keyboard inputs (up, down, left, right arrows) and 2) a Gamepad UI (up, down, left, right buttons).  Any suggestions to how I could regulate my directional changes?

```
    void Start () {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        isPaused = false;
        InvokeRepeating("TimerInvoke", 0, deltaTimer);
    }

    void TimerInvoke() {
    Movement();
    StartCoroutine(checkVisible());
    if (currentSize == maxSize)
        TailFunction();
    else
        currentSize++;
    }

    void Update () {
         CompDirectionControl();
         PauseCMD();
    }

    void CompDirectionControl() {
    if (direction != Direction.South && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        direction = Direction.North;
    if (direction != Direction.West && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        direction = Direction.East;
    if (direction != Direction.North && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        direction = Direction.South;
    if (direction != Direction.East && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        direction = Direction.West;
    }

    public void  MPadDirectionControl(int numDirection)
    {
    if (direction != Direction.South && numDirection == 0)
        direction = Direction.North;
    if (direction != Direction.West && numDirection == 1)
        direction = Direction.East;
    if (direction != Direction.North && numDirection == 2)
        direction = Direction.South;
    if (direction != Direction.East && numDirection == 3)
        direction = Direction.West;
    }
```

I tried creating something like this but the delay is very inconsistent

```
    if (Time.time >= timeStamp)
    {
        CompDirectionControl();
        timeStamp = Time.time + moveInterval;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I was able to add a delay to my keyboard inputs by using a coroutine.  However, I have not figured out how to do the same with my button UI inputs.  If I create a public IEnumerator GamePadDirControl(int direction), how do I pass my button's parameter to my IEnumator?  Even though I set my GamePadDirControl to public, I don't see it in my Inspector so I can't link my button to it

```
IEnumerator DirControl() {
    if (direction != Direction.South && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTimer);
        direction = Direction.North;
    }
    else if (direction != Direction.West && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTimer);
        direction = Direction.East;
    }
    else if (direction != Direction.North && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTimer);
        direction = Direction.South;
    }
    else if (direction != Direction.East && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTimer);
        direction = Direction.West;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
For my buttons UI - Since it isn't possible for my button to link up with IEnumator functions, I decided to create individual coroutines for each direction and call on them from my public void MPadDirectionControl(int numDirection) function.

updated code on button ui input

```
public void MPadDirectionControl(int numDirection)
{
    if (direction != Direction.South && numDirection == 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(IntervalN());
        //direction = Direction.North;
    }
    else if (direction != Direction.West && numDirection == 1)
    {
        StartCoroutine(IntervalE());
        //direction = Direction.East;
    }
    else if (direction != Direction.North && numDirection == 2)
    {
        StartCoroutine(IntervalS());
        //direction = Direction.South;
    }
    else if (direction != Direction.East && numDirection == 3)
    {
        StartCoroutine(IntervalW());
        //direction = Direction.West;
    }
}

IEnumerator IntervalN() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTimer);
    direction = Direction.North;
}

IEnumerator IntervalE()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTimer);
    direction = Direction.East;
}

IEnumerator IntervalS()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTimer);
    direction = Direction.South;
}

IEnumerator IntervalW()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTimer);
    direction = Direction.West;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand your question ...

Your trying to change the direction before a delay ?

If so, I will try:

```
StartCoroutine(ChangeDirectionTo(Direction.North, 0.05f));
IEnumarator ChangeDirectionTo(Direction direction, float delay) {
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
   this.direction = direction;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Emanouil I'm trying to add a delay to my inputs (both keyboard and to buttons UI).  To "move" my snake, I run a InvokeRepeating() set to an interval in which my program creates a cube in the user's selected direction.  While I coded my inputs so that the snake cannot move backwards (i.e. if snake is going north, it cant go south), the issue is the user currently can move the snake backwards if the user changes the direction faster than unity can move the snake (i.e. snake is going north, user changes direction to east and then south causing the snake to run into itself when frame finishes

Comment: Hmm, I saw your update, and the Coroutines solved a half of your problem.

About access the coroutines in inspector for link it to your button, I usually solve this problem by creating an auxiliary public function (void not IEnumator) and call the couroutine from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was playing around and came up with the same thought.  I created individual coroutines for each direction and then call on them from my public input function.  Seems to be creating the delay I need now!

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. You need to distinguish between the *current* direction of the snake, and the user's *commanded* direction. Try something like this:

```
if (direction != Direction.South && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    nextDirection = Direction.North;
if (direction != Direction.West && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    nextDirection = Direction.East;
if (direction != Direction.North && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    nextDirection = Direction.South;
if (direction != Direction.East && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    nextDirection = Direction.West;
}
```

Then in the code where you actually create the cube, just before spawning it, use nextDirection to tell you where the player wants to go:

```
direction = nextDirection;
```

Thus the player simply doesn't have the chance to change the direction before the cube is spawned.

This should work, but it has the disadvantage that you won't get the nice "input buffering" effect that some snake games have, where you can tap Right, Down while the snake is going north to do a U-turn. If you want to do that, you'll have to implement some kind of smart buffering system that detects if the player puts in a very specific kind of "invalid" input (north/south when direction is north and nextDirection is east) and sets the snake up for a future direction change. Kind of like buffering "special move" inputs for a fighting game.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nat

Comment: I found a solution by using a coroutine on my direction control and it works with my keyboard inputs.  However,  I am still looking for a solution with my button UI inputs. I don't know how to run a coroutine that uses a parameter passed in from by buttons